# ERC1155 Batch updates best practice

Tags: erc-1155

What is the most gas efficient way of doing Batch updates (ERC1155).

e.g. A key within 100 tokens must be changes to 'active'.

Comment: Batch and update a very generic terms. Can you be more specific about what it is your trying to update in batch?

Comment: Hi at this time, I haven't written the smart contract itself, nor used ERC1155. I wish to mint 10,000 tokens with an; x, y, z axis of 0. When a user buys the tokens they may wish to move the co-ordinates of each of them.